# R count occurrences in a list of numerical vector

Tags: r, list

I have this list of genes and genomic positions of matches

```
$HES2
 [1] 6472685 6472960 6473183 6473556 6473721 6473880 6474011 6474016 6474021
[10] 6474026 6474031 6474036 6474595 6475487 6475525 6475625 6475843 6475847
[19] 6475851 6476040 6476416 6477257 6477498 6477543 6478033 6478181 6480077
[28] 6481025 6481370 6481426 6483450 6483762 6483892 6484023 6484664

$HGFAC
[1] 3444133 3444265 3445567 3448970 3449333 3450621
```

I want to count the occurrences in a segment bin, let's say of 100 base pairs and report the gene and the counts in this particular segment, let me show you dummy data

```
HES2  6474026-6474126  150
HES2  6475038-6475138  589
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: How are you getting 150 and 589?

Comment: Also, please provide exact input and output formats. From the description, the last object you provided seems to mix both inputs (bins) and outputs (frequencies).

Comment: first you should reshape this list into a long data structure of type data frame. then you can handle it much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I am missing something, but is this what you are after?

```
HES2<-c("6472685" ,"6472960" ,"6473183" ,"6473556" ,"6473721" ,"6473880" ,"6474011", "6474016" ,"6474021","6474026" ,"6474031" ,"6474036" ,"6474595", "6475487", "6475525" ,"6475625", "6475843", "6475847","6475851", "6476040" ,"6476416", "6477257", "6477498", "6477543" ,"6478033" ,"6478181" ,"6480077","6481025" ,"6481370", "6481426" ,"6483450" ,"6483762" ,"6483892", "6484023" ,"6484664")

HES2<-as.numeric(HES2)
bin_w<-100
h=hist(x=HES2,breaks=bin_w,plot=FALSE)
counts<-data.frame(from=h$breaks,to=h$breaks+bin_w,count=c(h$count,0))
counts[which(counts$count>0),]

      from      to count
1  6472600 6472700     1
4  6472900 6473000     1
6  6473100 6473200     1
10 6473500 6473600     1
12 6473700 6473800     1
13 6473800 6473900     1
```

Comment: Thanks Troy, is a beginnning, but I think it could work applying to a list

Comment: @user976991 , take Troy's answer and then see `?ldply` in the `plyr` package.